# IE 11. Why have I click and dblclick events after reload page if I double click a submit button

Tags: internet-explorer-11, double-click

I have a simple html page and event handlers on submit button and form. Event handler function print to console what is event appers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="formId" method="post">
    <input id="inpSbm" name="inpSbm" type="submit" value="SubmitTest" class="lockDoubleClick"/>
</form>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("on ready");
        $(".lockDoubleClick").each(function () {
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.click(function () {
                console.log("click")
            });
            btn.dblclick(function () {
                console.log("double click")
            });
            btn.closest('form').submit(function () {
                console.log("submit form");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

In IE11 when I double click on submit button I see the following in console:

```
click 
submit form
on ready
click
double click
```

Why have I click and double click event after page is ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because double-click is one of the most stupid ideas in the history of computing.

There are users who can double-click very quickly. There are others who can barely get in under the time limit that is the only difference between a double click and two singles. This means that when the computer sees the first click it must wait for a very long time to see if the user is going to click again. Users hate this; it makes the interface seem very slow.

The only solution is to have a 'double-click' actually hit the application as two clicks. They are identical except that the second one has a little flag that says it came in under the deadline for a double-click.

If against all reason you must accept both a double-click and a single-click on the same object you MUST be able to reverse the effect of the first click when the second user gets around to actually pushing the button for their very belated double-click.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
But why have I events after load page?

Comment: The new page doesn't save any state from the old page (except what you explicitly specify) the single click triggers the reload but then a double click arrives for the new version of the page ... except that page hasn't had a single click first so to make it 'right' it needs the single click event that was 'somehow' lost before it can have the double click. But in reality it didn't get a single click so the submit isn't actually activated (probably).